# Python exercise about finding indices of X in the list

Tags: python, list, indices

```
def leesFormulier(l1):
    index = 0
    lres = []
    for j in range(len(l1)):
        for k in range(0,9,2):
            if l1[j][k] == 'X':
                lres.append(index+1)
                index += 1
            else:
                index += 1
    return lres
print(leesFormulier(l1 = ['1 X 3 4 X', 'X 7 X X 10', '11 12 13 14 15', '16 17 18 19 20', '21 22 23 24 25', '26 27 28 29 30', '31 32 33 34 35', '36 37 38 39 40', '41 42 43 44 X']))

result : [2, 5, 6, 8, 9]
```

Hello everybody,

I'm making an exercise on Python and I have to find the indices of where you can find the 'X'. And I solved it for the most part but the only problem I'm having is the last 'X' that won't be recognized. I put it in Pythontutor and there I could see that on the last time going through the for loops that it goes to the last k for loop but it doesn't check it but instead goes immediately to the j for lus and then ends the iteration and goes to the return part. I don't know what I'm doing wrong, would appreciate it if somebody could help me out.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't need all those indexes or nested loops for this problem and you can simplify it a lot

```
def lessFromulier(l1):
    lres = []
    new_string = " ".join(l1).split(" ")
    for i, letter in enumerate(new_string):
        if letter == "X":
            lres.append(i+1)
    return lres


test = [
    "1 X 3 4 X",
    "X 7 X X 10",
    "11 12 13 14 15",
    "16 17 18 19 20",
    "21 22 23 24 25",
    "26 27 28 29 30",
    "31 32 33 34 35",
    "36 37 38 39 40",
    "41 42 43 44 X",
]
print(lessFromulier(test))
```

which gives this output

```
[2, 5, 6, 8, 9, 45]
```

Answer (score 0):

Your input is really weird to me, but here is a solution to your question

```
def leesFormulier(l1):
    index = 0
    lres = []
    for i in range(len(l1)):
        for j in range(len(l1[i])):
            c = l1[i][j]
            if c == ' ':
                continue
            if c == 'X':
                index += 1
                lres.append(index)
            else:
                index += 1
    return lres

print(leesFormulier(l1 = ['1 X 3 4 X', 'X 7 X X 10', '11 12 13 14 15', '16 17 18 19 20', '21 22 23 24 25', '26 27 28 29 30', '31 32 33 34 35', '36 37 38 39 40', '41 42 43 44 X']))
```